# Constraints SSIS - is it possible to enable chosen package after something is executed?

Tags: ssis

I'm pursuing my project where I have a multi-layer SSIS project. Basic structure is as follows:

```
|-- Package level 0 (MASTER package that contains references to other packages)

    |-- Package level 1 Bulkimport (many csvs into db)  
        |-- Package level 1.1 Bulkimport tests
            |-- Execute SQL task testing the upload correctness
            |-- DataViewer (DataFlow - ODBC connection + multicast) displaying tests result
```

I'm starting from an empty db. I take all files from a given folder and I'm uploading them using level 1 Package. This bulkimport is connected with sequence container holding package refference to level 1.1 package Bulkimport tests and to the DataViewer showing tests results. I'm passing variables to display results with DataViewer.

Two annoying issues:

1. When I'm opening the solution (empty db, no data uploaded yet) I can't execute whole level 1 Package with Bulkimport because my DataViewer (by variable) cannot find results that are created within test package. Thus I need to disable my tests package and firstly execute bulk import. How to avoid that?
2. In long term it is expected to execute every package from the 0 Master Level, but the table with the tests results appears only when I'm executing level 1 package, when I'm executing 0 level package my DataViewer doesn't appear. How to fix that?

Comment: For your first issue; have you tried to set "DelayValidation" on true?

Comment: I found a way around, at the very beginning i put a sql with preprocessing that is fouling my project - creates empty tables to be used later - thanks to that the build is not throwing the error. Later in the project the right data is inserted into tables. Thanks for your input :)